# SAS - how to find variable name in string which is similar to a specified sub-string

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to find if a variable exisits in a string (&fixed) and if so, which word number.

```
%LET fixed = %STR(variable1 region1 variable3);

%IF %INDEX(&fixed, regio) %THEN
  %DO;
    %LET regioxc = %SCAN(&fixed, %SYSFUNC(FIND(&fixed, regio)));
  %END;
```

I want to create a macro variable called regioxc, which could be equal to either region1 one time, and the next time the macro is run it could be equal to regiodc, or something else (always with the beginning string 'regio'), if that is the region variable specified within the &fixed string. This only works if the regio variable is specified first within the &fixed string, but in this case it is the second variable, so this does not work. I cannot find a robust method of creating the variable (word) count value from the &fixed string to be able to use the scan function. I know it should be 2, in this case. Any help here would be much appreciaited.

Comment: Could you please provide some example inputs and results?  I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry this is messy, not sure how to put onto separate lines. 
What I want to end up with is:


%LET fixed = %STR(variable1 region1 variable3);

%IF %INDEX(&fixed, regio) %THEN
  %DO;
    %LET regioxc = %SCAN(&fixed, 2);
  %END;

&regioxc = region1.


The next time this is run the fixed string has changed to the following:


%LET fixed = %STR(variable1 regio44 variable3);
%IF %INDEX(&fixed, regio) %THEN
  %DO;
    %LET regioxc = %SCAN(&fixed, 2);
  %END;

&regioxc = regio44.

Comment: Next time it might be %LET fixed = %STR(var1 var2 regioxxd); The value for SCAN needs to find this regio variable, so in this case it should be 3.

Comment: You put it on separate lines by editing it into the question :)  A good example would be having three or four input strings and three or four equivalent desired outputs, either in a table or in SAS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit easier to see this using data step functions.  What you want to do is use the `index` result to inform `substring`, then use `scan` on that substring.  That way it's *always* the first word.  `scan` looks for which # of word, remember, not which position.  If you were `find`ing a whole word you could use `findw` or `indexw`, but since you're finding only a part of a word but want the whole thing returned, you can't really do that.

```
data want;
  fixed="variable1 region1 variable3";
  if index(fixed,"regio") then do;
    regioxc = scan(substr(fixed,index(fixed,"regio")),1);
  end;
  put _all_;
run;
```

In macro variables you can still do this:

```
%LET fixed = %STR(variable1 region1 variable3);

    %LET regioxc = %SCAN(%substr(&fixed,%index(&fixed,regio)),1);

%put &=regioxc;
```

(I leave out the `%if` to make it easier to see it work, of course in production code put it back in.)